# Symfony2 findBy+indexBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In query builder you can specify which field should be used as array index:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('s');
$qb->from('models\Settings', 's', 's.key');  // here the magic
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
//here $result[key] is entity
```

Anybody knows how to add indexBy(not in DB, but index of array of results)  to the findBy method, or make findBy-like method for repository, something like:

```
$clients = $clientRepository->findBy(['id' => $clients], [indexBy=>id]);
```

OR

```
$clients = $clientRepository->myFindByWithIndexBy(['id' => $clients], 'id');
```

I need a method with filter criteria (where) and it should return entities indexed by id.

Comment: What are you meaning by "`indexBy` not in DB" ?

Comment: @Veve I mean that indexBy is NOT related to DB at all. IndexBy is index by in array, not order by in DB http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

Answer (score -3):

Second argument to findBy is for ordering results (indexing in database context is another thing).

```
$repo->findBy(['id'=>$clients], ['id'=>'asc']); // reverse by changing 'asc' to 'desc'
```

Comment: That is not true.